# Modify plot axis so the order of its tick labels and their respective points change accordingly - without modifying the data itself

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to reorder x-axis tick labels such that the data also changes appropriately.

**Example**

```py
y = [5,8,9,10]
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
plt.plot(y, x)
```

[image: Original plot]

What I want the plot to look like by modifying the location of axis ticks. 
[image: Intended image]

Please note that I don't want to achieve this by modifying the order of my data

**My Try**

```
# attempt 1
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
plt.plot(y,x)
ax.set_xticklabels(['b', 'c', 'a', 'd'])
# this just overwrites the labels, not what we intended

# attempt2
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
plt.plot(y,x)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks((1,2,0,3)); # This is essentially showing the location 
# of the labels to dsiplay irrespective of the order of the tuple.
```

**Edit:** 
*Based on comments here are some further clarifications.*

Let's say the first point `(a,5)` in fig 1. If I changed my `x-axis` definition such that a is now defined at the third position, then it gets reflected in the plot as well, which means, `5` on `y-axis` moves with `a` as shown in fig-2. One way to achieve this would be to re-order the data. However, I would like to see if it is possible to achieve it somehow by changing axis locations. To summarize, the data should be plotted based on how we define our custom axis without re-ordering the original data.

**Edit2:**
Based on the discussion in the comments it's not possible to do it by just modifying axis labels. Any approach would involve modifying the data. This was an oversimplification of the original problem I was facing. Finally, using dictionary-based labels in a pandas data frame helped me to sort the axis values in a specific order while also making sure that their respective values change accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with matplotlib alone. However, seaborn is a package that wraps matplotlib, and you could probably find a solution using seaborn.

Comment: You need to change the order of `y` as well. I would maintain a `dict` for mapping or have different series with proper order

Comment: @iamchoosinganame this problem arose while using seaborn. the box plot in seaborn picks the labels based on what appears first in the dataframe. So, I thought it would be simpler to reorder it using `matplotlib` API

Comment: @mad_ this is a simpler version of the problem I'm facing. I have an interactive plot based on some condition for a data frame. The order appears as expected until I take the condition to extreme and `seaborn` starts plotting the order based on what it sees first in the dataframe. I was hoping for a simple lower-level approach to just re-order the ticks-labels.

Comment: So is all of this now about the order of seaborn's boxplots or really about simple matplotlib line plots?

Comment: @SpghttCd if I found a matplotlib solution, I can also apply the same to seaborn. However, at this point, if Seaborn has some higher axis re-ordering function then that would work too for my case. In any case, if it's possible by seaborn then assuming then it should also be possible only by using matplotlib axis functions as well since Seaborn is wrapped over matplotlib?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Do you have a preferred order of `x` and you want to plot `x[order], y[order]`?

Comment: It's important to distinguish any potential boxplot problem from the problem in this question. The code in the question (`plt.plot(["a", "b"], [1,2])`) uses matplotlib's categorical feature, while usual boxplots (matplotlib or seaborn) use numerical positions and label the ticks. This is to say, please ask about the actual problem, not about something you think is related.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest maybe I should think of how to ask my original problem in a reproducible manner as a separate question. Certainly, this looks as an over-simplification of the problem and is possibly more confusing. Thanks for pointing out the difference.

Comment: In any case, there is no functionality for reordering scales in matplotlib (and hence also not in seaborn). I could still show a way to toggle between two desired orders for the case shown in this question if you are interested?

Comment: As an update to the original problem I was facing, it is much easier to sort the values in a given order and pandas dictionary-based approach took care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Toggling between two different orders of the x axis categories could look as follows,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
y = [5,8,9,10]

order1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
order2 = ['b', 'c', 'a', 'd']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, marker="o")

def toggle(order):
    _, ind1 = np.unique(x, return_index=True)
    _, inv2 = np.unique(order, return_inverse=True)
    y_new = np.array(y)[ind1][inv2]

    line.set_ydata(y_new)
    line.axes.set_xticks(range(len(order)))
    line.axes.set_xticklabels(order)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

curr = [0]
orders = [order1, order2]
def onclick(evt):
    curr[0] = (curr[0] + 1) % 2
    toggle(orders[curr[0]])


fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onclick)

plt.show()
```

Click anywhere on the plot to toggle between `order1` and `order2`.

Comment: The plot didn't toggle while clicking. I'm running this code on jupyter notebook connected via tunnel on a remote computer.

Comment: Yep, that would not allow for interactivity. In that case just call `toggle(order1)` or `toggle(order2)` to see either of the two solutions.